# Is it true that whole system space address space in linux does not use demand paging?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, windows-kernel

I am currently studying windows and I found that windows uses two sections of memory that they have named paged pool and nonpaged pool in system space address space. So only the critical sections of windows are kept in nonpaged pool(which does not use demand paging). While I was taught that in linux all the system space address space does not use the concept of demand paging? If all that information is correct then should I conclude that windows require less amount of RAM to run than linux??

Comment: Even if Windows allows some parts of the kernel to be paged out (and Linux doesn't), it does NOT automatically follow that Windows uses less RAM than Linux.

Comment: The Linux kernel does not allow itself to be swapped out. http://sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/linux-kernel/swap.html

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency yeah you are right!! I must not conclude just by looking at one factor. But the thing is even if the linux kernel is lighter, they could have build it more lighter?? Then they have chose such heavy implantation??

Comment: Yes, in theory Linux *could* have a lower RAM footprint by allowing itself to be swapped out. But seriously, why? Trying to do that is extremely complex. Remember, Linux *already* runs on the majority of SmartPhones, most TVs, most routers, virtually all of the top 500 super computers, etc..  Contrast this to Windows where (as I understand it), it's not a single OS running on desktop and Windows phones.

Answer (score 1):

```
While I was taught that in linux all the system space address space does not use
the concept of virtual memory?
```

This is wrong. Linux kernel and it's components (drivers, subsystems etc) use virtual memory. Function pointers, pointers returned by allocation routines are virtual addresses.

Comment: can you give me a link that proves what you stated?? The memory return by the vmalloc() will be virtually contiguous, but here by virtual memory i just meant demand paging. Sorry for not being specific in my question, i have edited it now though !!

Comment: I answered your question. Your edit came late though I think the stuff about vmalloc is not quite right. I will remove it.

Comment: ?? i didn't get the answer yet!! read this 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-kernel-memory-access/
more specifically this 
"Although kernel pages are not candidates for swapping"

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about memory management, I hope the words below can answer it.

In Linux, there's two kinds of memory address spaces: virtual and physical.
Memory is managed in page unit.
Virtual address is mapped to physical address.
virtual address is the address you use when writing your code.
physical address can be in memory, in disk or somewhere else.
Disk is less expensive and larger than memory, but memory is faster than disk.
So kernel prefers to use memory.
To get space for greedy process, kernel will swap some page from memory to disk, so free memories are available.

But most memories in kernel address space should not be swapped to disk, because they're responsible for managing the kernel and all other things. this is similar to nonpaged pool of windows.

I think both of linux and windows have similar memory manage mechanics.
So it's hard to say which uses less.

Comment: "But most memories in kernel address space" it is most or all ?? that I need to know?

Comment: After some search, I think all kernel space is not swappable. swap is just related to process. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

Comment: The url above also contains an paragraph of **demand paging**

Comment: yeah this is what I said in my question :) !!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel uses virtual memory for vmalloc allocations, but it is always backed by physical memory. This means the kernel never page faults. It keeps latency predictable. The few kernel subsystems that access storage (mm, nfsd, file-backed swap) have to explicitly ask the vfs to map pages; this keeps the complexity where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel image part of the kernel space can not be swapped out not the entire kernel space. For example, page cache which is backed by disks can absolutely be paged out when physical memory becomes low.