# Does Linux Kernel have equivalent of Windows' Paged and Nonpaged Pool memory allocation?

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver

I've been working with Linux kernel mode modules for a short while, and it doesn't seem like Linux provides a memory allocation type of "Paged Pool" like Windows OS does for kernel mode drivers.  Is nonpaged (locked/non-swappable) memory the only type of memory that a Linux kernel module can allocate for its own internal use?

Looked through a number of Linux resources, and it appears that all kernel mode allocations for kernel mode use are non-paged.  There is the "page_pool_create" and associated APIs.  But those require the driver to carefully lock pages before using them.  I'm looking for allocated memory that driver functions can access directly and, if a page-fault occurs, the normal OS paging mechanism kicks in and handles it without the driver being aware, the same as the OS would for a user-mode allocation that can be swapped out.  A Windows' kernel driver has to ensure it only uses such memory when it is running at low IRQL (i.e. not at dispatch or interrupt level), but with proper design, that is what most of a driver's code runs at.  The posting: "[Is it true that whole system space address space in linux does not use demand paging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953598)"
basically tells me "No, there is nothing like 'paged-pool' for kernel mode use."  But that posting was ten years ago.  Has there been any change?

Comment: Doesn't sound like something I'd expect from a monolithic kernel like Linux.  Sounds very much like a feature of a microkernel, as the NT kernel was/mostly still is, with drivers being closer to user space processes.  Maybe you could have a user space daemon that is used to provide the same functionality?